# how to implement a button with a tab activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a tab activity and then in one of those activities i want to place a button to take to a different activity.  However when i code the button (getting no errors) but when launching the app it crashes with error code:

`11-14 12:50:43.783: E/AndroidRuntime(10933): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dist.distguide/com.dist.distguide.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

However when i remove the button coding the app launches fine.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/logo1">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Distancecalc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Distance Calculator" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Distance"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Distance Calculator" />

    </FrameLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>
```

And then my Java:

```
Intent intentHome = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecHome = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("Home")
        .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_home_config))
        .setContent(intentHome);
    Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Distance1);
    add.bringToFront(); 
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DistanceCalc.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);  
         }
    });
```

What am i doing wrong here?
Please help!
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Distance1);
```

to

```
Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Distancecalc);
```

Your Button id is `Distancecalc`. and you're trying to initialize it with `Distance1`.

Comment: Sorry one more thing,  I have placed another button in but its not showing when launchin the app.  it seems the button is missing. any ideas or a link i can go to to correct this?

Comment: I have tried but it seems to just put the button behind the first button,  I have updated my question